# Why doesn't Flow support constants in exhaustive check?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I wonder why doesn't Flow support constants? How to work with redux action types constants? To create flow literal type for every single action type? It's unreal! How to work around that?

```
const S: 'S' = 'S';

function foo(arg: typeof S): number {
  switch(arg) {
      // string literal 'S' give no error
      case S:
        return 42;
    default:
      return (arg: empty);
      //      ^ Cannot cast `arg` to empty because string literal `S` [1] is incompatible with empty [2].
  }
}
```

Comment: What `arg: empty` is supposed to mean (given it's typed as `typeof S` already)?

Comment: @zerkms it means like "regardless type `arg` has not passed while calling function". Check example at https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/#toc-typing-redux-reducers

Comment: Daryn, could you be more specific on what do you want to achieve? can your `arg`  to be only 'S' or undefined? what do you mean by mixing `return` and type assertion `(arg: empty)` together?

Comment: Someone edited my post and added code (it's not mine). I don't like this: const S: 'S' = 'S'. Because I have many action types, for example: const SEND_COMMENT_REQUESTED = 'SEND_COMMENT_REQUESTED' etc etc... Writing 3 times the same is not good approach.

Comment: Oh, and once again. I didn't write about exhaustive check (it's not my title and not I'm asking about)